# C# File.ReadAllBytes() Only reads first 9k bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I've been trying to read a file byte by byte so that i can create it later just from my single .exe file.
I tried to read individual bytes of that file and load em into a byte array.
But when i tried reading them using this program

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ok
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] buffer = null;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Praca\programowanie\Visual Studio\C#\ok\ok\bin\Debug\net5.0\temp.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= 13025; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(buffer[i].ToString() + ",");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It does return individual bytes, but it only returns the first 9000 or so bytes, and closes the program.
Can anyone help me here?
I'll happily provide more details if needed

Comment: Why the arbitrary `13025`?

Comment: Aside: try to avoid loading files entirely into memory if possble, especially if they're this large. You can read from a stream bit-by-bit

Comment: `byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("filename");`?

Comment: 13025 is the size of the file.
Also, can you elaborate on that stream bit-by-bit method? I'm interested

Comment: Instead of allocating a buffer which is large enough to hold the entire file, allocate a buffer which is e.g. 1024 bytes large, and repeatedly read 1024 bytes into it, then print those to the console, then repeat... You can even have a 1-byte buffer (so read 1 byte, print it, read another byte, print it, etc), and it probably won't cost you much performance

Comment: You've got the size of the file as `fs.Length` and also `buffer.Length`, so you can just use that instead? Also looping until `i <= 13025` will read `13026` bytes

Comment: Just for clarity, i solved that. I realised just now that 9000 is the line limit on the CMD window, and it was cutting the first bytes. I was only reading the LAST 9000 bytes.

I do know that it will read 13026 bytes, that's the correct size.

I need to store the whole file in the program so that i can create it later on, without having the original file.

Comment: Store it as an embedded resource, then. Add the file to your project, and under its "Properties", set "Build Action" to "Embedded resource". Read it back later with `typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("nameOfFile.docx")`

Comment: I tried writing that resource to disk, and this came up:
File.WriteAllBytes("doc.docx", typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("docum.docx"));
ErrorCS1503: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'byte[]'

Comment: `using (var resourceStream = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("docum.docx")) using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("doc.docx")) { resourceStream.CopyTo(fileStream); }`

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`
resourceStream was null.
At line `resourceStream.CopyTo(filestream);`

Comment: Make sure you're passing the right filename to `GetManifestResourceStream`, and also that you correctly added the file as "Embedded resource". Use `GetManifestResourceNames()` to return a list of resource names if you want to check what name it has. There are plenty of articles on doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a stupid question.
It turns out that it reads it all just fine, but 9000 is the size limit by the CMD window.
I'll just read the first 8500 bytes, and add them manually.

Comment: What are you doing with the output? If you're writing them into a file, then you can redirect with e.g. `MyConsoleApplication.exe > SomeFile`